# IK + Pole Target {Rig} is =//= Twisting my Characters Mesh

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

When i apply this rig i have here to my test model.
With automatic weights. It totally twists my model.
Any clue whats causing this? I tried to mess with the poles rotation.
And i tried to apply rotation and scale.. nothings helping.

Picture:
[image]

Edit:
I found out that when i disable the Pole targets it seems to do it right.
But how can i make it right with poles enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turning on Axes for the bones can be really helpful when things twist, and/or before parenting mesh to rig. Like it seems in your case, the twist occurs when you parent mesh to rig with Auto-Weights.

I suspect a complete bone rotation in Y axis in one step, (Y axis is Up for bones)

So probably step 1 can solve it, step 2) 3) are more indepth regarding IK.

[image]
What happens if you change IK Solver to iTaSC
[image]
Sometimes adding stiffness can solve at least weird rotational behaviour.
[image]

Comment: Ok cool i will have a go at this later :) ty!