# My IK rigging is backwards. Twisting the mesh and pointing the wrong direction

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I am an amateur rigger at best. I do not have much of a grasp on the technical side of it, so this probably seems very stupid.

My rig is putting a "knot" in my mesh and will only work if the IK is flipped completely away from the pole target. One of my feet is also askew and I don't understand why. The mesh and rig are perfectly mirrored (or so i thought.)

I'm really not sure how I screwed up, I would really appreciate some advice.

This post seemed to have the same problem
[IK + Pole Target {Rig} is =//= Twisting my Characters Mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/ik-pole-target-rig-is-twisting-my-characters-mesh)
but I don't understand their solution. I tried changing the IK solving to iTaSC but that didn't help.

The arm bends in the exact opposite direction that it should be bending.

When I rotate the pole angle so the rig works correctly, the mesh deforms and twists into a knot. 
[image: Knot in the arm]

Here is my .blend
[image]

Comment: By perfectly mirrored do you mean renaming the bones?

Comment: bones are mirrored. As well as the names. Re-set the rotation and placement of the bones and you will see that. Or just go into edit mode. The picture is just to show the problem.

Comment: @Uglyfire could you please explain with screenshots what is the exact problem?

Comment: It only lets me post two links at once, so I'll get a better picture.